# Bootstrap Nav issue

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, drop-down-menu, wordpress-theming, nav

I have  problem with my nav bar on a theme I am developing. http://astanmedia.com/blog All is ok at full screen, but reduce the screen size so the the menu collapses and when you click / touch the toggle button, the dropdown refuses to break over the slider, no matter what z-index is set, or positioning used. on scroll I have the nav change to fixed at the top, and it displays fine once the slider has passed it. The dropdowns also function fine over the slider at full screen. Have tried to paste code here for 15 minutes, I must be doing it wrong, so I have linked to a paste bin of the code here http://pastebin.com/6war9TGu. Thanks in advance

Comment: fix your code errors https://validator.w3.org/nu/?doc=http%3A%2F%2Fastanmedia.com%2Fblog%2F

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I see your problem.  It's not the z-index, it's the navbar-collapse style.

You have:

`.navbar-collapse { max-height: 50px; }`

You need something like:

`.navbar-collapse { max-height: 275px; }`

According to the Google Chrome developer tools, you can find the `.navbar-collapse` style on line 106 of your style.css.  In your Pastebin it looks like it's on line 94.

As a note, once you fix the `.navbar-collapse` max-height, you'll also need to add a background color to your `.navbar .navbar-nav` class so that the drop down menu doesn't have a transparent background.

I'm seeing a few other little things on your style that may need adjustment, but I'm going to assume that you'll ask specifically about these issues as you go.  To fix the question you asked about, the `navbar-collapse` should help.

Comment: Thanks a lot, forgot that I had even set a max-height on that. removing it solves the issue altogether.

Comment: Glad I was able to help.